# Clean CSS (atomic approach) vs clean HTML, which is faster?

Tags: html, css, atomic

It seems there are two major schools of thought on how to structure CSS and HTML. I was taught to keep the HTML as clean as possible, and all things stylistic should be on the stylesheet.  This has served me well thus far, but with this approach I often notice redundancies and inefficiencies.

I read up on the [atomic approach](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/21/challenging-css-best-practices-atomic-approach/), and I really like the idea. It seems to be the method I naturally gravitate toward anyway.

**My question:**
Which way is really faster, considering the two following blocks of code:
HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <h1 class="m-10 theme-c1">header with margin and theme color 1</h1>
  <p class="fz-1 theme-c1 m-10">paragraph with font-size 1em.</p>
  <div class="m-10">
    <p class="fz-1 m-10">blah</p>
    <p class="sub-paragraph">Sub paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
/*margin-left rule*/
.ml-10 {margin-left: 

/*font-size rule*/
.fz-1 {font-size:1em}

/*theme color*/
.theme-c {color: #333};

/*display rule*/
.dps-blk {display: block}
/
/*sub paragraph styles*/
.sub-paragraph {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-color: #333;
}
```

Elements in the HTML above all get whatever style they need, and the styles above are non-descendants except for `.sub-paragraph`.

So is it faster for each element to cherry pick which styles it needs, or is it better to just give it a chunk of styles (like for `.sub-paragraph`)?  With `.sub-paragraph`, I can see how it only takes one match to get all the styles.  The trade off, however, is that there isn't much else you can do with that set of styles except use it on sub-paragraph, or override some of its properties with another rule when applied to something else.

I'm think with these two approaches, it's a decision on whether to the cost on data size or on processing time.

**Edit**
<strike>I appreciate all the feedback. I forgot to mention that I'm specifically interested in the processing speeds of the different approaches.</strike>
This is interesting nonetheless.

Comment: I'm assuming this is just a transcription error, but you've got a slash just above the `.sub-paragraph` block that will be preventing the `.sub-paragraph` selector from working.

Comment: Huh, I was doing this 10 years ago. That project lives on and I replace those "atomic styles" every chance I get. Applying styles at a low level of borders and background colors leads to inconsistency. I want consistency in my interface and this approach is contrary to that goal.

Comment: @hsin It has been around more than four years since you asked this. I recently was thinking about the same and came across your question. I hope you'd have an answer now. Can you please help me and others who land here by telling which approach you chose and was it as maintainable as you expected? Would you switch to another one? Does atomic CSS mean more processing time?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to begin cherry picking individual styles, you would end up with a stylesheet like:

```
.red{ color: red; }
.green-background{ background: green; }
.w500{ width: 500; }
.ml20{ margin-left:20px; }
```

Which is not very maintainable.

It sounds like what you are looking for is a way to extend certain classes (i.e. `.sub-paragraph`) with pre-existing classes, adding the styles of other classes into `.sub-paragraph`. [SASS's](http://sass-lang.com/) [`.extend`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) directive is a great way of doing this.
Sass and other preprocessors are great at merging the ideas of maintainable code and semantic code together.

#### Edit 1:

If you are looking into which method (more classes/less properties or less classes/more properties) is faster, I would suggest doing some testing with Chrome Dev Tools' [Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline#timeline_event_reference). The two methods of coding aren't the only thing that are going to affect how fast a page renders/paints, so it is always a good idea to test these if you are concerned about speed.

Comment: +1 I think that for sites being independently or privately developed maintainability is key.  How long to download or draw is usually a minor consideration.  In a couple of years the hardware will make it fast anyway.  Whether a web site continues to be usful and maintained will come down to how well it was contructed in the first place.  Exceptions might be things like one-page brochure sites with a guaranteed life-span.  In my experience though, if it works well that life-span turns out to want to be extended.

Comment: @Fillip: I'm actually more curious about the difference in processing speeds. But I agree in regards to what you're saying about preprocessors.
As for your CSS example--sorry, I've misled you with the example in my original post.  I wouldn't be so specific with colors and pixel numbers in my class names.  It would be something more like .this-region-padding or .that-widget-display.

Comment: I see. Sorry your question got derailed. I've made some edits. Hopefully they help a bit with your intended question.

Comment: @FillipPeyton: Not at all a problem. It was my poor explanation that caused the misunderstanding to begin with.
Thank you for the timeline link. Although I don't think I've found my answer yet, I think it's somewhat coming together in my mind. I understand other factors can affect render/paint speed; I wanted to look at this factor for now and focus on the other ones later.

Comment: Sounds good. Hope you find what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I organize my CSS by grouping certain types of classes together. When creating CSS classes I ask myself, am I going to reuse this class definition for anything else? Is it logical for me to separate this class' definition, will someone who has to read this after me want to shoot themselves?

Basically I would say, go for maintainability, an extra 1Kb on your Css will not choke anyone.

Comment: @llya: sorry for the late response. Thank you for sharing your thought process when creating classes.  I certainly would hate for someone to shoot themselves over my codes; it just seems like an unnecessary step of the styling process.

As for maintainability--yes, I definitely want it to be maintainable, but the question is which approach is more maintainable?  And in regards to file size, 1 extra Kb on a smaller site won't do much, but on a large scale, it could count for a lot. And to better future-proof it, I'd like to keep as minimalized as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a place for both.
I don't feel that the abstraction belongs at class names like `.p1-gr-brdr`, though.

If you're writing very tightly-composed, atomic HTML partial-templates (for things like AngularJS directives), then you'd likely get more mileage out of `.title`, `.subtitle`, `.just`, `.content`, where you can specify very specific output for those components.

Changing those components will be very simple and straightforward, as they're so compact and self-contained.

And if you find yourself in a position where you need to override one, to compose an inherited class, then you either have the option of composing a new class-name, which now might not be 100% semantic/generic (".big-green-subtitle"), but is still 100% self-contained for those moments where you want your special-cases to feel loved, too...

...or you can then specify behavior with a second-level selector.

If your `.header` has a padding, but you don't want your `.update > .header > .subtitle` to be subject to that padding-bottom, on mobile-phones, in landscape orientation, on Tuesdays, then you can simply have an exception which states `.update > .header { padding-bottom : 0; }`.

Otherwise the cascade will continue as normal, and things will either pile on top of one another, or you will cancel out side-effects with specialized classes which cover the same properties...

Otherwise, I don't see why all CSS sheets don't look like:

```
.p1-br { border-width : 1px; }
.p2-br { border-width : 2px; }
.p3-br { border-width : 3px; }
.p4-br { border-width : 4px; }

.gr-br    { border-color : green;        }
.lgtgr-br { border-color : lightgreen;   }
.sfmgr-br { border-color : seafoamgreen; }
.aqmr-br  { border-color : aquamarine;   }

.em1-wd { width : 1em; }
.em2-wd { width : 2em; }
.em3-wd { width : 3em; }

.rm1-wd { width : 1rem; }
.pc1-wd { width : 1%;   }
```

...et cetera, until you've written out every atomic option you could possibly want, for any theme your project (and all of its components) might want to support, across all platforms.

That seems like a terrible use of your day, to write a unique class-name for every possible edge-case out there:

```
<div class="pos-rel
            p1-br
            p18-ng-tp
            mrpc12-br-r
            lggr-bg
            bg-im-spr-id-123
            pc15-bg-im-algn-lf
            ofl-x-hd
            ofl-y-aut
            brd-bx">
```

Seems hefty for a single div, for instance.

This would *not*, however, be a bad idea, if you could write CSS rules, give them to classes, where you expect flexibility, and later had the hard-numbers to those rules.
Such that, say, you write out a class which expects to treat height in `rem`s, margins in `percent`s, border-radius in `em`s, will take a background-colour and an image-sprite (say it's a backdrop container for a corporate/retail site, with a watermark and logo, where other content will scroll above it).

Now you want to reuse that set of classes on the same component, but for a different client...

It would help if you could simply have some variables, which could live in a separate file, and be referenced by your classes, so that your units don't necessarily need to change, but you can modify all of your hard-coding stuff in one or two places, and swap different variable values in for different clients as easily as pointing at a different sheet...

...but that's what SASS already does, if you take the time to sit down and figure out how you want to engineer something, and make your build process adhere to that desired outcome.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your thoughts. Although I'm not looking so much at how preprocessors can help with structuring CSS, but more so on the difference of approaches when writing CSS. Consider this: instead of reusing those codes for different clients, you take the rules down a level and make them reusable throughout the site at a smaller level. For example, you might want to always have the same left padding on several different elements, and while SASS can do this for you, the question is whether they should be in different classes or share the class that determines, say, theme-padding.

Answer (score -1):

CSS is designed to use classes for certain groups of styles. The `.sub-paragraph` method is usually way better than the seperate classes method. If you are going to assign classes for each style seperately, you might as well just use inline styles, via the `style` attribute. You should usually try to avoid that for maintenance reasons though.

Comment: -1 for inline styles.  An absolute nightmare to maintain and debug as many web developers have learned.  Save learning the lesson and do it right from the get-go and trust that when tens of thousands of developers spend 10 years learning this basic fact, it's probably something you should accept.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant happy now? I meant to say it in the way of 'if you're gonna do it like that, you might as well do this bad thing'. I guess trying to communicate things like that through the internet doesn't work then...

Comment: Please refer to the link I posted in the topic, as it addresses the inline issue.  Giving several classes is not the same as doing inline styles.  For example, if you had 5 elements all with the same inline styles--say, padding: 10px; font-size: 1em; font-height 1.6em--then to change those you would have to do that in 5 places, whereas you would only have to make changes to 3 CSS rules.  Scale that and I'd imagine it'd quickly make a difference.